# AzureADLogs Powershell - audit when a user has been disable or enabled

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

So I am trying to find out the Azure AD logs via PowerShell, when a user has been enable or disabled, specially the date & time and preferably who did it as well.

I've tried using the follow, but I am not sure what I am supposed to be looking for.

```
Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "createdDateTime gt 2023-05-30" | SELECT *
```

or

```
Get-MgAuditLogSignIn -Filter "createdDateTime ge 2023-05-29T00:00:00Z  and createdDateTime le 2023-06-03T00:00:00Z"
```

How can I filter to just when someone has been enabled or disabled?
I know how to find the disabled users with

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $False}
```

but I just need to know who and when they were disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whenever user account is enabled or disabled, it will be saved with
> **Activity name** as `Enable account` and  `Disable account` respectively in Audit logs.

You can run below command to check who and when users are **disabled**:

```
Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs -Filter "activityDisplayName eq 'Disable account' " | where-object Result -eq "Success" | fl
```

**Response:**

[image]

Similarly, you can run below command to check who and when users are **enabled**:

```
Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs -Filter "activityDisplayName eq 'Enable account' " | where-object Result -eq "Success" | fl
```

**Response:**

[image]

To get the same results using **Microsoft Graph PowerShell**, you can check below commands:

**Disabled users:**

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Reports
Get-MgAuditLogDirectoryAudit -Filter  "activityDisplayName eq 'Disable account' and result eq 'Success'" | fl
```

**Enabled users:**

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Reports
Get-MgAuditLogDirectoryAudit -Filter  "activityDisplayName eq 'Enable account' and result eq 'Success'" | fl
```

Comment: You can't say `Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs -Filter "activityDisplayName eq 'Disable' and Result eq 'Success'"`?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I ended up using Get-MgAuditLogDirectoryAudit